# Java to Qt code convert

Tags: qt

I'm teaching my self Qt; in the same time I don't want to lose my Java skills in Qt.
I stacked in some codes to do it in Qt, I tried many times as well as search in the net.

Code # 1

```
Object[] names = jList1.getSelectedValues();
String msg = "";
for (Object o : names)
msg += o;
```

Code # 2

```
DefaultListModel model;
model = new DefaultListModel();
jList1.setModel(model);
```

Code # 3

```
if(!jList1.isSelectionEmpty())
I didn't find Empty method :-(
```

I'm going to do some Qt's video tutorials on youtube, but before that I need to solve the above codes.
If any programmer can help I will be thankful;

Thanks in advance

At the end I would like to thanks the experts who are spent thier value times to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want for code #1 and #3 is the [selection model](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). It does not have an empty method, but `hasSelection` aught to do it for you.

As for code #2, you could use the [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstandarditemmodel.html). It could be considered the default model if you must, but having a standard model in most cases defeats the purpose of the model-view paradigm (proving a model interface to your actual data). You could also look into the `QList`/`Tree`/`TableWidget` classes, as they come with a model (which `QList`/`Tree`/`TableView` don't).

Comment: First of all I'm very happy to hear from you



hasSelection serves their purpose, Thanks



Code #1 



How is to define Object array with no size, Array of Object type in Qt?



Code #2



I'm using QtableWidget, Below Another NOT working example using Qt



    QTableWidget *model = new QTableWidget;
    QString cn[] = {"Hamad","Al Ketbi"};
    model = new QtableWidget(cn,0);
    ui->tableWidget->setModel(model);



Many Thanks again

Comment: #1, list without size (or rather, size 0): "QList<QObject*> list; list << &o1 << &o2 << &o3;", remember that QObjects are not values, they are individuals (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/object.html#identity-vs-value). 
#2 If you want a model of strings, simply use a QStringListModel (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstringlistmodel.html#details).

Comment: I will give it try tonight at home, I hope to translate your idea.
Sometime I'm asking my self why people help others? it's really kindly from you and the people behind this site